# Fortnite glitch with black trees

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Recently when I've been playing Fortnite, a glitch has made it so all the trees have black leaves. Also, I cannot see chests that spawn near me, and it glitches me out of the ground when I walk. Are there any helpful suggestions that may improve these problems for me?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, I think you should try restarting your computer and when it happens, restarting your game (closing and reopening). If you play on console, I think you should close Fortnite and reopen it.

Comment: I have tried that, it continued after I shut down my computer, and closed the game.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling? It normally fixes things with me. It also might be a graphics card error and you need to turn down your fortnite graphics settings

Comment: It went away now... Didn't play for a week and when I came back, it was fixed?